# Prove or disprove $\bot\vDash \psi$

Tags: logic

> Prove or disprove with counter-example:
>
> $$\bot\vDash \psi$$
>
> For all formula $\psi$

I can't show what I did because I have no idea how to start, so please I need some hints, thank you.

Comment: To prove this, you need to know what methods of proof are allowed. We cannot guess that - it need to be specified in the question.

Comment: @CarlMummert What do you mean "what methods allowed"?, thank you for downvote

Comment: I mean the question of which proof methods are allowed. In many systems of formal logic, $\bot \to \psi$ is a basic inference rule - so it has a one-line proof by merely noting that it is an inference rule. Presumably that is not what you want, but without any additional details about what system you are using there is no way to tell what kind of justification would be acceptable.

Comment: The other area in which this question could be improved is by adding context. Where did you encounter this problem? Why is it of interest? In fact, there is no "question" in this post at all, only what appears to be a quote of a problem from a textbook or assignment. Posts of that kind are discouraged.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, it is a quote from my textbook assignment, so what?? I asked for hints, what should I do this is a new material for me, I didn't asked "please do my homework", your downvote is not in the right place

Comment: Quoting from a textbook on its own is OK, but for example you could easily indicate which book you are using, and in general could make the post *more* than just a quote from a textbook. That kind of post - which is nothing more than a copy of a textbook problem - is hard to answer, and in general does not contribute towards a library of high-quality posts that this site aims to be.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: it's a double turnstile, so the OP does not need to say anything about a proof system: the question can be solved by semantics alone. The "prove or find a counterexample" imperative is asking for a proof or counterexample in the metalanguage.

Comment: @CarlMummert Why should I indicate the book that I'm using?, $90\%$ of the posts here on MATH.SE does not do that, why should I do that?, and it is not hard to answer it is a fact that **Mauro ALLEGRANZA**  answered very quickly

Comment: @Error404 Because the notion of logical consequence is not really that universal: depending on your logical system, as said by Carl Mummert, this may just need a one line proof. Thus, this question fits perfectly the "Lacking context or details" reason for closing.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Stupid downevote for clear question, thank you for downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to show that each *valuation* [or *model*] that satisfy $\bot$ will also satisfy $\psi$ ( see: [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) ).

Assume not, i.e. there is a valuation $v$ such that $v(\bot)=$**t** and $v(\psi)=$**f**.

But there is **no** valuation $v$ such that $v(\bot)=$**t** !

Answer (score 2):

Another way of approaching this problem is by using the deduction theorem. This says that $X \models \alpha \iff \models X \rightarrow \alpha$. So we have that $\alpha$ is a logical consequence of $X$ if and only if $X \rightarrow \alpha$ is a tautology. Now it is obvious from the truth table of an implication that $\bot \rightarrow \alpha$ is a tautology.